# Deleting all the nodes in a tree - C++

Tags: c++, tree, destroy

Trying to implement a `deleteTree` method in C++. This method takes the root of the tree as parameter and should consequently delete all nodes from the root to the leaf. My code seems to be logically correct, however I get an infinite loop each time I run it. Could anyone identify what is wrong ?

```
template <class A, class B> void Tree<A,B>::deleteTree(Node<A,B>* rootNode) {
    if (rootNode->left != NULL) {
        deleteTree(rootNode->left);
    }
    if (rootNode->right != NULL) {
        deleteTree(rootNode->right);
    }
    free(root);
}
```

Comment: does your tree have a circle?

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, that would be quite an interesting tree

Comment: Why use `free` instead of `delete`? Do you use `malloc` instead of `new`? Or `free` is a function you wrote?

Comment: @Leeor people make mistakes, do they? :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code never actually frees any node except `root`, but that multiple times. Also you need to set the pointer to `NULL` manually after that. `free` won't do that for you.

However this does not exactly explain the behaviour. I would expect a segmentation fault. (Well actually it causes undefined behaviour) You probably created a loop in the graph by accident somewhere.

Also `free` will not call the destructor, which might have unintended side effects. You should use `new`/`delete` instead or try some data structure which doesn't require manual allocation at all.

Comment: that is not true, due to the recursion

Comment: He's right, root isn't defined here, he should free rootNode. Nice catch!

Comment: @thumbmunkeys The only free frees `root` which seems to be a member of `Tree<A,B>`